# Show textbox when a radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show a textbox when a radio button within a radio button group is selected. I am using a script named iCheck written by "Damir Sultanov", to change radio buttons in to images. The radio button part works fine but when I add the input textbox and the Jquery functions to deal with the click of a radio button the textbox will not show.

I have a jsfiddle to try and demo what the issue is.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#PatTestDate").hide();
  });

  $(function() {
    $("#Action1_2").click(function() {
      $("#PatTestDate").show();
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
  });
});

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').each(function(){

 var self = $(this),
    label = self.next(),
    label_text = label.text();

    label.remove();
    self.iCheck({

      //checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_line',
      radioClass: 'iradio_line',
      insert: '<div ></div>' + label_text
    });
  });
  
 $('#Action1_2').on('ifChecked', function(event){
   $( "#PatTestDate" ).show();
 });
 
  $('#Action1_1').on('ifChecked', function(event){
   $( "#PatTestDate" ).hide();
 });
  $('#Action1_0').on('ifChecked', function(event){
   $( "#PatTestDate" ).hide();
 });
  
$(".remove").on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().prev('label.prfx-row-title').remove();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});

});

(function($) {

  // Cached vars
  var _iCheck = 'iCheck',
    _iCheckHelper = _iCheck + '-helper',
    _checkbox = 'checkbox',
    _radio = 'radio',
    _checked = 'checked',
    _unchecked = 'un' + _checked,
    _disabled = 'disabled',
    _determinate = 'determinate',
    _indeterminate = 'in' + _determinate,
    _update = 'update',
    _type = 'type',
    _click = 'click',
    _touch = 'touchbegin.i touchend.i',
    _add = 'addClass',
    _remove = 'removeClass',
    _callback = 'trigger',
    _label = 'label',
    _cursor = 'cursor',
    _mobile = /ipad|iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|windows phone|opera mini|silk/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

  // Plugin init
  $.fn[_iCheck] = function(options, fire) {

    // Walker
    var handle = 'input[type="' + _checkbox + '"], input[type="' + _radio + '"]',
      stack = $(),
      walker = function(object) {
        object.each(function() {
          var self = $(this);

          if (self.is(handle)) {
            stack = stack.add(self);
          } else {
            stack = stack.add(self.find(handle));
          }
        });
      };

    // Check if we should operate with some method
    if (/^(check|uncheck|toggle|indeterminate|determinate|disable|enable|update|destroy)$/i.test(options)) {

      // Normalize method's name
      options = options.toLowerCase();

      // Find checkboxes and radio buttons
      walker(this);

      return stack.each(function() {
        var self = $(this);

        if (options == 'destroy') {
          tidy(self, 'ifDestroyed');
        } else {
          operate(self, true, options);
        }

        // Fire method's callback
        if ($.isFunction(fire)) {
          fire();
        }
      });

      // Customization
    } else if (typeof options == 'object' || !options) {

      // Check if any options were passed
      var settings = $.extend({
          checkedClass: _checked,
          disabledClass: _disabled,
          indeterminateClass: _indeterminate,
          labelHover: true
        }, options),

        selector = settings.handle,
        hoverClass = settings.hoverClass || 'hover',
        focusClass = settings.focusClass || 'focus',
        activeClass = settings.activeClass || 'active',
        labelHover = !!settings.labelHover,
        labelHoverClass = settings.labelHoverClass || 'hover',

        // Setup clickable area
        area = ('' + settings.increaseArea).replace('%', '') | 0;

      // Selector limit
      if (selector == _checkbox || selector == _radio) {
        handle = 'input[type="' + selector + '"]';
      }

      // Clickable area limit
      if (area < -50) {
        area = -50;
      }

      // Walk around the selector
      walker(this);

      return stack.each(function() {
        var self = $(this);

        // If already customized
        tidy(self);

        var node = this,
          id = node.id,

          // Layer styles
          offset = -area + '%',
          size = 100 + (area * 2) + '%',
          layer = {
            position: 'absolute',
            top: offset,
            left: offset,
            display: 'block',
            width: size,
            height: size,
            margin: 0,
            padding: 0,
            background: '#fff',
            border: 0,
            opacity: 0
          },

          // Choose how to hide input
          hide = _mobile ? {
            position: 'absolute',
            visibility: 'hidden'
          } : area ? layer : {
            position: 'absolute',
            opacity: 0
          },

          // Get proper class
          className = node[_type] == _checkbox ? settings.checkboxClass || 'i' + _checkbox : settings.radioClass || 'i' + _radio,

          // Find assigned labels
          label = $(_label + '[for="' + id + '"]').add(self.closest(_label)),

          // Check ARIA option
          aria = !!settings.aria,

          // Set ARIA placeholder
          ariaID = _iCheck + '-' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 6),

          // Parent & helper
          parent = '<div class="' + className + '" ' + (aria ? 'role="' + node[_type] + '" ' : ''),
          helper;

        // Set ARIA "labelledby"
        if (aria) {
          label.each(function() {
            parent += 'aria-labelledby="';

            if (this.id) {
              parent += this.id;
            } else {
              this.id = ariaID;
              parent += ariaID;
            }

            parent += '"';
          });
        }

        // Wrap input
        parent = self.wrap(parent + '/>')[_callback]('ifCreated').parent().append(settings.insert);

        // Layer addition
        helper = $('<ins class="' + _iCheckHelper + '"/>').css(layer).appendTo(parent);

        // Finalize customization
        self.data(_iCheck, {
          o: settings,
          s: self.attr('style')
        }).css(hide);
        !!settings.inheritClass && parent[_add](node.className || '');
        !!settings.inheritID && id && parent.attr('id', _iCheck + '-' + id);
        parent.css('position') == 'static' && parent.css('position', 'relative');
        operate(self, true, _update);

        // Label events
        if (label.length) {
          label.on(_click + '.i mouseover.i mouseout.i ' + _touch, function(event) {
            var type = event[_type],
              item = $(this);

            // Do nothing if input is disabled
            if (!node[_disabled]) {

              // Click
              if (type == _click) {
                if ($(event.target).is('a')) {
                  return;
                }
                operate(self, false, true);

                // Hover state
              } else if (labelHover) {

                // mouseout|touchend
                if (/ut|nd/.test(type)) {
                  parent[_remove](hoverClass);
                  item[_remove](labelHoverClass);
                } else {
                  parent[_add](hoverClass);
                  item[_add](labelHoverClass);
                }
              }

              if (_mobile) {
                event.stopPropagation();
              } else {
                return false;
              }
            }
          });
        }

        // Input events
        self.on(_click + '.i focus.i blur.i keyup.i keydown.i keypress.i', function(event) {
          var type = event[_type],
            key = event.keyCode;

          // Click
          if (type == _click) {
            return false;

            // Keydown
          } else if (type == 'keydown' && key == 32) {
            if (!(node[_type] == _radio && node[_checked])) {
              if (node[_checked]) {
                off(self, _checked);
              } else {
                on(self, _checked);
              }
            }

            return false;

            // Keyup
          } else if (type == 'keyup' && node[_type] == _radio) {
            !node[_checked] && on(self, _checked);

            // Focus/blur
          } else if (/us|ur/.test(type)) {
            parent[type == 'blur' ? _remove : _add](focusClass);
          }
        });

        // Helper events
        helper.on(_click + ' mousedown mouseup mouseover mouseout ' + _touch, function(event) {
          var type = event[_type],

            // mousedown|mouseup
            toggle = /wn|up/.test(type) ? activeClass : hoverClass;

          // Do nothing if input is disabled
          if (!node[_disabled]) {

            // Click
            if (type == _click) {
              operate(self, false, true);

              // Active and hover states
            } else {

              // State is on
              if (/wn|er|in/.test(type)) {

                // mousedown|mouseover|touchbegin
                parent[_add](toggle);

                // State is off
              } else {
                parent[_remove](toggle + ' ' + activeClass);
              }

              // Label hover
              if (label.length && labelHover && toggle == hoverClass) {

                // mouseout|touchend
                label[/ut|nd/.test(type) ? _remove : _add](labelHoverClass);
              }
            }

            if (_mobile) {
              event.stopPropagation();
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      return this;
    }
  };

  // Do something with inputs
  function operate(input, direct, method) {
    var node = input[0],
      state = /er/.test(method) ? _indeterminate : /bl/.test(method) ? _disabled : _checked,
      active = method == _update ? {
        checked: node[_checked],
        disabled: node[_disabled],
        indeterminate: input.attr(_indeterminate) == 'true' || input.attr(_determinate) == 'false'
      } : node[state];

    // Check, disable or indeterminate
    if (/^(ch|di|in)/.test(method) && !active) {
      on(input, state);

      // Uncheck, enable or determinate
    } else if (/^(un|en|de)/.test(method) && active) {
      off(input, state);

      // Update
    } else if (method == _update) {

      // Handle states
      for (var each in active) {
        if (active[each]) {
          on(input, each, true);
        } else {
          off(input, each, true);
        }
      }

    } else if (!direct || method == 'toggle') {

      // Helper or label was clicked
      if (!direct) {
        input[_callback]('ifClicked');
      }

      // Toggle checked state
      if (active) {
        if (node[_type] !== _radio) {
          off(input, state);
        }
      } else {
        on(input, state);
      }
    }
  }

  // Add checked, disabled or indeterminate state
  function on(input, state, keep) {
    var node = input[0],
      parent = input.parent(),
      checked = state == _checked,
      indeterminate = state == _indeterminate,
      disabled = state == _disabled,
      callback = indeterminate ? _determinate : checked ? _unchecked : 'enabled',
      regular = option(input, callback + capitalize(node[_type])),
      specific = option(input, state + capitalize(node[_type]));

    // Prevent unnecessary actions
    if (node[state] !== true) {

      // Toggle assigned radio buttons
      if (!keep && state == _checked && node[_type] == _radio && node.name) {
        var form = input.closest('form'),
          inputs = 'input[name="' + node.name + '"]';

        inputs = form.length ? form.find(inputs) : $(inputs);

        inputs.each(function() {
          if (this !== node && $(this).data(_iCheck)) {
            off($(this), state);
          }
        });
      }

      // Indeterminate state
      if (indeterminate) {

        // Add indeterminate state
        node[state] = true;

        // Remove checked state
        if (node[_checked]) {
          off(input, _checked, 'force');
        }

        // Checked or disabled state
      } else {

        // Add checked or disabled state
        if (!keep) {
          node[state] = true;
        }

        // Remove indeterminate state
        if (checked && node[_indeterminate]) {
          off(input, _indeterminate, false);
        }
      }

      // Trigger callbacks
      callbacks(input, checked, state, keep);
    }

    // Add proper cursor
    if (node[_disabled] && !!option(input, _cursor, true)) {
      parent.find('.' + _iCheckHelper).css(_cursor, 'default');
    }

    // Add state class
    parent[_add](specific || option(input, state) || '');

    // Set ARIA attribute
    if (!!parent.attr('role') && !indeterminate) {
      parent.attr('aria-' + (disabled ? _disabled : _checked), 'true');
    }

    // Remove regular state class
    parent[_remove](regular || option(input, callback) || '');
  }

  // Remove checked, disabled or indeterminate state
  function off(input, state, keep) {
    var node = input[0],
      parent = input.parent(),
      checked = state == _checked,
      indeterminate = state == _indeterminate,
      disabled = state == _disabled,
      callback = indeterminate ? _determinate : checked ? _unchecked : 'enabled',
      regular = option(input, callback + capitalize(node[_type])),
      specific = option(input, state + capitalize(node[_type]));

    // Prevent unnecessary actions
    if (node[state] !== false) {

      // Toggle state
      if (indeterminate || !keep || keep == 'force') {
        node[state] = false;
      }

      // Trigger callbacks
      callbacks(input, checked, callback, keep);
    }

    // Add proper cursor
    if (!node[_disabled] && !!option(input, _cursor, true)) {
      parent.find('.' + _iCheckHelper).css(_cursor, 'pointer');
    }

    // Remove state class
    parent[_remove](specific || option(input, state) || '');

    // Set ARIA attribute
    if (!!parent.attr('role') && !indeterminate) {
      parent.attr('aria-' + (disabled ? _disabled : _checked), 'false');
    }

    // Add regular state class
    parent[_add](regular || option(input, callback) || '');
  }

  // Remove all traces
  function tidy(input, callback) {
    if (input.data(_iCheck)) {

      // Remove everything except input
      input.parent().html(input.attr('style', input.data(_iCheck).s || ''));

      // Callback
      if (callback) {
        input[_callback](callback);
      }

      // Unbind events
      input.off('.i').unwrap();
      $(_label + '[for="' + input[0].id + '"]').add(input.closest(_label)).off('.i');
    }
  }

  // Get some option
  function option(input, state, regular) {
    if (input.data(_iCheck)) {
      return input.data(_iCheck).o[state + (regular ? '' : 'Class')];
    }
  }

  // Capitalize some string
  function capitalize(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  }

  // Executable handlers
  function callbacks(input, checked, callback, keep) {
    if (!keep) {
      if (checked) {
        input[_callback]('ifToggled');
      }

      input[_callback]('ifChanged')[_callback]('if' + capitalize(callback));
    }
  }
})(window.jQuery || window.Zepto);
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.icheckbox_line,
.iradio_line {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: margin: 5px 5 0 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #666;
  background: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

.icheckbox_line .icheck_line-icon,
.iradio_line .icheck_line-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: -10;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.icheckbox_line.hover,
.icheckbox_line.checked.hover,
.iradio_line.hover {
  background: #339900;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.icheckbox_line.checked,
.iradio_line.checked {
  background: #CC0000;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.icheckbox_line.checked .icheck_line-icon,
.iradio_line.checked .icheck_line-icon {
  background-position: -40px 0;
}

.icheckbox_line.disabled,
.iradio_line.disabled {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
}

.icheckbox_line.disabled .icheck_line-icon,
.iradio_line.disabled .icheck_line-icon {
  background-position: -30px 0;
}

.icheckbox_line.checked.disabled,
.iradio_line.checked.disabled {
  background: #ccc;
}

.icheckbox_line.checked.disabled .icheck_line-icon,
.iradio_line.checked.disabled .icheck_line-icon {
  background-position: -45px 0;
}


/* HiDPI support */

@media (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4),
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
(min-resolution: 120dpi),
(min-resolution: 1.25dppx) {
  .icheckbox_line .icheck_line-icon,
  .iradio_line .icheck_line-icon {
    background-image: url(line@2x.png);
    -webkit-background-size: 60px 13px;
    background-size: 60px 13px;
  }
}

.iline_div {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio]+label {
  background: #999;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  background: #0080FF;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="FixBox">
  <input type="radio" name="iCheck[<?php echo $row_TQ01['SeqID']; ?>]0" value="2" id="Action1_0">
  <label class="hidden" for="Action1_0">Fix</label>
</div>
<div class="FailBox">
  <input type="radio" name="iCheck[<?php echo $row_TQ01['SeqID']; ?>]0" value="1" checked id="Action1_1">
  <label for="Action1_1">Fail</label>
</div>
<div class="PassBox">
  <input type="radio" name="iCheck[<?php echo $row_TQ01['SeqID']; ?>]0" value="0" id="Action1_2">
  <label class="hidden" for="Action1_2">Pass</label>
</div>


<div id="PatTest">Test date:</div>
<div id="PatTestDate">
  <input name="PatTestDate" type="text" class="PatTestDateTest" id="datepicker" size="12" placeholder="PAT Test date">
</div>
```

Comment: Add relevant code here at SO. Don't make fool of system by adding fiddle link as code

Comment: How do I add my link to the fiddle?

Comment: Instead of giving link, create the snippet here itself.

Comment: just add a snippet instead of a jsfiddle, using SO's built-in tool

Comment: Why are you wrapping yout $(function in $(document.ready? Not necessary at all

Comment: You likely need to read the iCheck documentation on events

Comment: @mplungjan Hi and many thanks for your feedback and help. I now have it working by adding the following to the "input" function: $('#Action1_2').on('ifChecked', function(event){
   $( "#PatTestDate" ).show();
 });
 
  $('#Action1_1').on('ifChecked', function(event){
   $( "#PatTestDate" ).hide();
 });
  $('#Action1_0').on('ifChecked', function(event){
   $( "#PatTestDate" ).hide();
 });. You were right concerning reading the iCheck documentation.

Comment: Add an answer with the solution

Answer (score -1):

To show `text input` on click of radio, you can follow following steps:

1. Create radio with same `name`
2. Capture event using `input[name='radioBtn']`. (radioBtn is the name given for the radio buttons)
3. Capture the input box using `$(inputBoxID)`
4. Use `.show` or `.hide` functions to show/hide the text box.

```js
var inputBox = $("#textInput");

inputBox.hide();

$("input[name=radioBtn]").change(function(e) {
  inputBox.val(e.target.value);
  inputBox.show();  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="2"/>
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="0"/>

<input type="text" id="textInput"/>
```

Comment: @downvoter: can you please explain why have you down voted the answer.